# Can't get existByProperty to run: "No property student found for type Student!"

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to write a "existsBy" query but can't make it work. I know there is a existByID in the JpaRepository, but I need to check by the property student_id. I have tried countless ways of writing the function name, but I can't seem to make it right.

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private long student_id;

+other fields and getters and setters...
```

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    boolean existsByStudentid(Long student_id);
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property student found for type Student!
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Data is using the underscore as a reserved character. I think it is not possible to use it this way. I think there is no other option to rename the variable.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

So the field must be named with the following convention

```
private long studentId;
```

(The underscore can be used for traversing nested properties: To resolve this ambiguity you can use _ inside your method name to manually define traversal points.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, there is too much code in both frontend and the backend of our project to change that now, although we might have to. But can I still use student_id  it in a custom query or will that also not run?

Comment: No I think it will work in a custom query. Because I also use underscores in my database instead of camelcase notation. For example: SELECT student_id FROM STUDENT should work.

Comment: I was thinking more specifically about the @Query annotation in the JpaRepository, how would I go about writing a query there with underscores in properties?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your property is student_id

So the query method should be

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    boolean existsByStudent_id(Long student_id);
}
```

Btw: _ in property name is not a recommended style in Java expect for constants

Comment: Same error: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property student found for type Student! I know I shouldn't use student_id, but I'm trying to synchronise a table from another DB using RabbitMQ, and there student_id is the PK. I don't know why it is called that. This is a bachelor thesis, and one of the other group members said that's the norm so I just went with it. But yeah, still got an error using  existsByStudent_id

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That also won't work, they need to use proper naming conventions, since spring makes assumptions. `existsByStudent_id`, will look for a Student object inside the current student object and then an id field inside that.

Comment: Thanks, but can I still use student_id it in a custom query or will that also not run?